# Are ES6 blocks only prevent function hoisting?

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

Someone please help me understand the following scenario:

```js
//Outer funtion 
function foo() {
  console.log('outer foo');
}

{
  //Inner function
  function foo() {
    console.log('inner foo');
  }
}

foo(); //Says "inner foo"
```

I assume that in the above case the Inner function's explicit deceleration is replacing the hoisted outer function after the block is executed.

Does this mean that ES6 blocks ONLY prevent function hoisting when declared inside?

**Update**

It is opined by many that the blocks are not effecting functions. But, please see the following scenario as per MDN -

> ```
> foo('outside');  // TypeError: foo is not a function
> {
>   function foo(location) {
>    console.log('foo is called ' + location);
>   }
>   foo('inside'); // works correctly and logs 'foo is called inside'
> }
> ```
>
> To be more precise, the block statement is preventing the function
>   declaration from being hoisted to the top of the scope. The function
>   is behaving as if it were defined as a function expression and, as
>   such, it is only the implicit variable declaration that gets hoisted
>   to the top of the scope

**Another update**

The documentation was wrong and it was just fixed by the expert who provided the selected answer.

Comment: A `function` declaration statement is always hoisted to the closest enclosing **function** scope, not block.

Comment: "closest enclosing function scope" as in up to the immediate enclosing block?

Comment: No, not *block*; **function**.  Simple blocks don't matter at all.

Comment: Well if it's not inside a function it's hoisted to the top of the code unit (like the contents of a `<script>` tag).

Comment: But - as per MDN, the the functions declared within blocks are not hoisted. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Comment: That page is wrong. MDN is a wiki.

Comment: Well - That was not expected truly! Thanks.

Comment: MDN says - In non-strict code, function declarations inside blocks behave strangely. Do not use them. 
 I think it is some kind of bug. 
Or if you know the answer why functions behave strangely inside a block, please comment it down. I have the same doubt. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I assume that in the above case the Inner function's explicit deceleration is replacing the hoisted outer function after the block is executed.

Function declarations, like `var` statements, are hoisted to the top of the function during the initial scan of the function before the code within it is executed.

Blocks aren't relevant to hoisting of `var` statements or function declarations (both of which has function scope). They only matter for `let` and `const` which have block scope.

Comment: But - as per MDN, the the functions declared within blocks are not hoisted. developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/

Comment: wow you're quick :) I was just about to mark it for technical review